# Other name for VGA socket?

Tags: components, connector, vga

I need a VGA socket for my project (preferably PCB mounted but that's not reevent probably). But I can't find such a thing at any of my usual suppliers.

I presume they have some other name I need to look for? Searching through the many thousand types of connector hasn't helped me so far...

So, my question is, what do I need to look for for a vga socket connector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean this one

[image]

that's known under different names, but the most common is **D-sub 15** (sub for subminiature, which is a bit odd, since it's not that small). Other names you might encounter are **mini D15** or **HD15**.

Comment: Yes that's the one!
Thank you, knowing what to search for was my problem :)

Comment: It;s called sub-miniature because it was smaller then the miniature connectors *when it was introduced*. Times have changed, and now we see it as being quite large.

Comment: Bit o' Trivia: The commonly accepted name is DB-15, however, the CORRECT name (that no one actually uses) is DE-15.  The second letter denotes the case size.  This stems from DB-25 being the old serial port cables (on what we now know as parallel port connector) switching to the 9 pin version.  Should have been DE-9, but was mistakenly called DB-9.  Since the VGA is the same size, it probably pulled in the DB designation.